# Can't get the kernels to connect with a conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have been doing a lot of research to try to figure this out but I cannot 'crack it'.

I have created an environment called 'stats' in Conda and would like to use it. So I go to VS code and then open an existing Jupyter Notebook. I choose the interpreter at the bottom left... I do not fully understand it but I leave it with the Conda base.

Then, in the actual jupyter notebook I choose a kernel on the top right, in this case I choose the environment I created 'stats'.

Then VS code shows a little notification at the bottom that says 'Switching kernel to 'Python 3.8.5 64-bit ('stats': conda)' but never switches and stays in 'Python 3' from Anaconda3.

Can anyone shed a bit of light? I feel so confused. I spent few hours trying to figure it out but I really can't. Microsoft youtube videos puts it as 'plug and play' or 'simple'. I really don't think it is. It's very confusing!

Comment: I just tried it and it worked no problem switching the environment. I realized after selecting the new interpreter, I do have to open the jupyter notebook again. Follow this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Yeah. It does not work for me. I wonder if I messed something else. It cannot connect o any envs except from conda base.

Comment: @Frank Jimenez -The interpreter environment in the lower left corner of VSCode and the environment in the upper right corner of Jupyter Notebook can be different. From your description, the Jupyter environment failed to switch to "stats", it may be the lack of packages supporting Jupyter. Does VSCode prompt you to install "ipykernel"? What has been installed in the "stats" environment?

Comment: That's it! You got it. I never thought of doing such thing. For any readers, conda install ipykernel and should work fine :)